# Extract parts from a url javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a noob about javascript, I need some part from a Url like:

```
https://lets-talk-saku-gie-sakura.c9users.io/sala/?sala=important
```

I just need the "important" part, I've used `location.search` but the result is:

sala=important

How can I resolve this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the strings. Normally, `location.search` starts from `?` onward. You remove `?` first using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice). Then, each param will be delimited by a `&`. Split by that first and you get an array of pairs. Then you go through each pair and split by `=`.